# Iris.data.csv - ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to run this code on Google colab, I got the ValueError: x and y must be the same size, I've tried multiple ways but none of them worked.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
columns = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width','class']
df = pd.read_csv('Iris.data.csv', header=None, names=columns)
X = np.array(df.iloc[:, 0:4])   
y = np.array(df['class'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30)

plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Where is your `'Iris.data.csv'` from?  If it is from sklearn.datasets can you provide code to download the file, otherwise provide a link to the file online somewhere please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you haven't thought enough about what kind of scatter plot you are trying to make.  The `X` array contains 150 samples of 4 parameters.  The `y` array contains the classes of each data sample.  How were you expecting the scatter plot to look?  Remember that a scatter plot can only plot data in two dimensions, not 4!

I don't know what your `'Iris.data.csv'` file contains but I used the copy of the iris data set from scikit-learn [as shown in this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html).

Usually, scatter plots of the Iris data set select two of the four dimensions and plot the points in these dimensions for each class using a different coloured point.

Something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :4]  # take the first 4 features
assert(X.shape == (150, 4))
y = iris.target
assert(y.shape == (150,))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30)

classes = np.unique(y)
assert(classes.shape == (3, ))

# Select dimensions to plot
dim1 = X[:, 0]  
dim2 = X[:, 1]

# Make a scatter plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for c in classes:
    pts = (y == c)
    ax.scatter(dim1[pts], dim2[pts])

ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]